# How to scribble backslash ("\") on Apple Watch?

Tags: password, apple-watch, watchos, text-input

My organization's WiFi username & password has punctuations in it. Namely a Windows-style `DOMAIN\user` username, which contains a backslash ("") character.

watchOS 6's "connect to" WiFi doesn't allow using the iPhone to enter passwords. This makes it really difficult to enter punctuations other than hyphen `-`, underbar `_` and period `.`.

Are there options here for entering odd characters or specifically this one?

Comment: Does your iPhone joining the WiFi not pass through to the watch?

Comment: @bmike I don't believe that works for these type of credentials

Comment: We had to make some changes with Cisco to ease this. Any chance your IT is open to making this work?

Answer (score 1):

watchOS 9 now supports using iCloud Keychain, or typing on the phone to enter the password on the watch.

These combined should make it possible now to join any network.

Answer (score -2):

Scribble feature of Apple watch can be awesome. It allows Apple Watch users to discreetly scrawl text replies on their wrists, no iPhone keyboard necessary.

While entering WIFI password, you should get a Scribble screen where you can write with your finger. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes. Can write. Can't enter backslash as it keep interpreting it as a `1` or `l`.

Comment: It is not that hard, as more flat \ will work easily. I am using Apple Watch 4 and never had an issue.

Comment: I find it impossible to type an Active Directory `DOMAIN\user` using Scribble. Adding a space before "\" often works, but without the space it keeps insisting `l`, `1`, or `_`. But AD usernames don't have spaces in them.